# Can I have global buffer in Android ? where other process can communicate or even from native c++ code

Tags: android, c++, message

I know we can have the Intents or Binder or AIDL to communicate however Can I have global buffer in Android ? where other process can communicate or even from native c++ code . It more like receiving the message from different process/services in my application.

suggestion are welcome :)

Comment: My impression is Binder is a kernel module, so in theory you should be able to use it in NDK code (without going back to Java and then JNI route).  But I have nothing to back my claim, perhaps search "Android access Binder NDK" might help...?

Answer (score 0):

How about a service that would act as a "server" and offer a socket connection to it to access its buffer.

Comment: as I said anything I can go with it too considering it a possible solution, can you pleas give or direct me to some sample base code.

my application client already has a socket client who is communicating with the remote device over usb, Fyi

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called a file. And since Android 2.3+ uses Ext4, delayed allocation will greatly reduce the number of physical accesses needed.

A slightly trickier solution is `/dev/ashmem/`, which can be lost in case of memory pressure since it's just in RAM.